# Copy details from a row and email

Tags: excel, vba

[please click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQfcb.jpg) How do I copy details on each row with the table header and send the copied data to the email address on that row?

I've tried multiple ways to resolve this but can't find a solution:

Basically, I just need to copy what is on a row, send the copied values to the email address on that row.

Here's my code:

```
Sub AutoSendMail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
            LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value) = "yes" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "VBA TEST"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Hello, this is a vba test, please ignore. " & _
                    "Thank you!"
                'You can add files also like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Display  'Or use Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value = "SENT"
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data

Comment: Hi Ricardo, you mean a screenshot of the sheet?

Comment: Hi, if you can, yes

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: Two questions for you **1.** Which column has email addresses? **2.** Which data (columns?) you want to show in the email?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, Column E has the email address and I want to Copy the header from column A:D, as well as a row under each header for each email

Comment: Hello Ricardo, I have added a link to the screenshot in my post. Thanks

Comment: SJR, there is currently no problem with the code. I just don't know how to add a code to copy some cells on a row and paste to the email body of mail address on the same row.

Comment: Hello all, I hope everyone understands my question now?